# Flutter CLI works in mac terminal but not in VSCode or Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, visual-studio-code

As a title, I don't know why their build in Terminal in VSCode or Android Studio are not working.

> bash: flutter: command not found

I have set Flutter path in **~/.bash_profile**. here is the result of `echo $PATH`

> /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Applications/Visual
>   Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin:**/Users/Mac/flutter/bin**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem it's because I use `$PWD` to substitute as a user path.

So instead of doing this in **~/.bash_profile**

```
# Flutter
export PATH="$PATH:$PWD/flutter/bin"
```

Change it to this

```
# Flutter
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/Mac/flutter/bin"
```